# How the client can get the server uploaded original file of filename and extension?

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, upload

Please help me I just a beginner of python and I want to learn this. I have no idea how to get the original filename and extension from the server part.

I try many ways and research but still cannot work it. I have seen many types of example those just can only upload text file with  `with open('received_file','.txt','wb') as f:` in the client part and cannot upload multiple type extension of files. I know because of the `'.txt'` so just work for text file. I don't how to declare to get multiple extension and original filename. This is my original code.

```
client


import socket
import os
TCP_IP = 'localhost'
TCP_PORT = 9001
BUFFER_SIZE = 8192

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
#data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)


with open('received_file','.txt','wb') as f:
    print ('file opened')
    while True:
        print('receiving data...')
        data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
        print('data=%s', (data))
        if not data:
            f.close()
            print ('file close()')
            break
        # write data to a file
        f.write(data)

print('Successfully get the file')
s.close()
print('connection closed')
```

> Blockquote

```
server


import socket
from threading import Thread
from socketserver import ThreadingMixIn
import tkinter
import tkinter.filedialog

TCP_IP = 'localhost'
TCP_PORT = 9001
BUFFER_SIZE = 8192
tkinter.Tk().withdraw() 
in_path = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename( )
class ClientThread(Thread):

    def __init__(self,ip,port,sock):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.ip = ip
        self.port = port
        self.sock = sock
        print (" New thread started for "+ip+":"+str(port))

    def run(self):
        filename= in_path
        f = open(filename,'rb')
        while True:
            l = f.read(BUFFER_SIZE)
            while (l):
                self.sock.send(l)
                l = f.read(BUFFER_SIZE)
            if not l:
                f.close()
                self.sock.close()
                break

tcpsock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
tcpsock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
tcpsock.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
threads = []

while True:
    tcpsock.listen(5)
    print ("Waiting for incoming connections...")
    (conn, (ip,port)) = tcpsock.accept()
    print ('Got connection from ', (ip,port))
    newthread = ClientThread(ip,port,conn)
    newthread.start()
    threads.append(newthread)

for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

The output file of name is received_file without the extension.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a protocol that transmits the filename, then the data.  Here's an example that transmits the content of `input.txt` to the client as the filename `output.txt`.  The client reads the filename, and then writes the data to that filename.  I did this simply because the client and server ran on the same computer, and read/write files in the same directory.

**server.py**

```
import socketserver

class MyTCPHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        filename = 'output.txt'
        self.request.sendall(filename.encode() + b'\r\n')
        with open('input.txt','rb') as f:
            self.request.sendall(f.read())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    HOST, PORT = "localhost", 9001
    with socketserver.ThreadingTCPServer((HOST, PORT), MyTCPHandler) as server:
        server.serve_forever()
```

**client.py**

```
import socket
import os
SERVER = 'localhost',9001

s = socket.socket()
s.connect(SERVER)

# autoclose f and s when with block is exited.
# makefile treats the socket as a file stream.
# Open in binary mode so the bytes of the file are received as is.
with s,s.makefile('rb') as f:
    # The first line is the UTF-8-encoded filename.  Strip the line delimiters.
    filename = f.readline().rstrip(b'\r\n').decode()
    with open(filename,'wb') as out:
        out.write(f.read())
```

Comment: Sorry, why the file I have chosen will become empty and cannot download for create a new file?

Comment: @Abalone If the client and server are running on the same system, you can’t use the same name for the input file and the output file; otherwise, you overwrite the input file when you open the output file.